# Is "for any" needed in "We dont want to stay here for any longer than we have to."?

Tags: grammaticality, ellipsis

> "We don't want to stay here **for any** longer than we have to."

Is this sentence correct? And does it mean the same as "We don't want to stay here any longer than necessary." ? I am unsure about the need of "for" and "any" maybe they can or should be left out to simply

> "We don't want to stay here longer than we have to."

Answer (score 1):

We don't want to stay here for any longer than we have to.

There's nothing wrong with the sentence; it's grammatical.

The word "long" also mean a long time or for a long time.  The preposition "for" in the sentence is optional, but we usually drop it when it's used in the said sense.

So the sentence will be more idiomatic without the preposition.

As for the use of the adverb "any" with  not in the sentence,  it's been used to emphasize the word "longer" in the sense of "not even a little bit".

If you don't want to emphasize the longer, you can drop the any.